# Need help understanding HTML 5 audio/video meta data use and placement

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video, video-encoding, html5-audio

I have spent a significant amount of time researching HTML 5 audio and video, however I am stuck understanding the encoding of the meta data. It seems that in my research, using programs like Handbrake (ffmpeg) it is recommend to check of "web optimized" (There is also a similar type of setting when exporting from other types of software, like imovie). I have concluded (and correct me if I am wrong) that this has to do with moving the file's meta data to the beginning of the file. This then gives the player/browser the info it requires to play immediately without having to wait to load the entire file.

So here is where I am confused and the question I need help with

Does this only apply to the mp4 MOOV atom? Or is there something similar in .ogv and .webm files?

Comment: Perhaps .ogv and .webm don't need this kind of manipulation? Although that's what I would like to believe :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the highly scientific method of seeing which Handbrake options are enabled when, I've determined that MOOV atom positioning is only relevant for MP4 container files.

More seriously though, the MOOV atom is part of the container file and there's no evidence that Ogg or WebM replicated this problematic feature of MP4.

From [the Ogg spec](http://xiph.org/ogg/doc/oggstream.html):

> The Ogg container is primarily a streaming format...

The [WebM "guidelines ... for file streaming over an HTTP connection"](http://www.webmproject.org/code/specs/container/#webm-guidelines) make no mention of MOOV atom position or anything similar, strongly suggesting that it's not an issue.

Comment: Is there any other meta info in the webm and ogv container formats that need to be placed at the beginning of the file for better web playback then?

Comment: @nicoz I didn't see anything in the documentation suggesting that.